# How to display progressbar before activity with GoogleMap is fully loaded

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a Mapview in one of my activity. Whenever a button is clicked and the activity which contains the Mapview is to be opened, it freezes the current activity UI until the activity with the MapView is fully loaded. I have the following code in my onCreate() method:

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    if(mMapView != null){
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
       mMapView.getMapAsync(JobDetail.this);
    }
```

and the activity itself implements OnMapReadyCallback:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(JobDetail.this);

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if(latitude!= null && longitude!= null){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(post_location));
        CameraPosition markposition = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(markposition));
    }
}
```

How can I darken the screen and display a progress bar until the activity with googlemapview is fully loaded and ready to be shown? I've read some answers suggest using Asynctask, but how can I do that with GoogleMapView?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is: show a progress when activity is called, inside the onMapReady() you dismiss or hide the progress and change the visibility property to VISIBLE.
Something like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(JobDetail.this);

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if(latitude!= null && longitude!= null){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(post_location));
        CameraPosition markposition = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(markposition));
    }

    mMapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> it freezes the UI until the activity is fully loaded

I don't think loading of Maps should freeze the UI in the first place. I've an app where in one activity the Map takes the entire real estate and another activity where the map occupying half the screen along with some image and text views. In both cases, I don't see any freeze in UI. See below my code snippet.

```
mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

try {
    Log.i(TAG, "initializing map");
    MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error while initializing map screen" + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
        googleMap = mMap;
        googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                mCameraReady = true;
                if(latitude!= null && longitude!= null){
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(post_location));
                    CameraPosition markposition = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(markposition));
                }
                googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(null);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It's similar to yours except for

1. The point where `MapsInitializer.initialize()` is called.
2. I wait for the camera to be ready before drawing the marker and zooming.

I don't think #1 matters, as per [Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer#public-methods), the call itself is not necessary. So give #2 a shot.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. Please see my edited question. What I meant was it freezes the current activity UI, before going into the activity containing MapView. Which i suspect it was loading googlemap before it is ready to be shown

Comment: I don't see how the mapview can freeze the current activity either.  I don't think the freeze is because of the map component at all. Did you try to remove the map component from the activity and check if the freeze issue goes away?